# How do I set multiple commands to an alias for Vim

Tags: wordpress, vim, ssh

I'm trying to create an alias to run tests in my Vim. But I get this error

> Not an editor command vagrant ssh -c 'cd /srv/www/wp-content/themes/project/ && phpunit'

Here's my `.vimrc`

```
command! Runtest execute "cd ~/ToMyProject | vagrant ssh -c 'cd /srv/www/wp-content/themes/project/ && phpunit'"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`:execute` is for evaluation of *Vimscript*; it appears you want to run *external commands*. To do so while observing the commands' output, use `:!`:

```
command! Runtest !cd ~/ToMyProject && vagrant ssh -c 'cd /srv/www/wp-content/themes/project/ && phpunit'
```

Alternatively, you could `:call system('cd ~/ToMyProject | ...')`; this would still block, but capture and return the output and exit status (which you could discard or inspect in Vimscript).

Comment: Thanks that works it looks like the `cd` command doesn't stay. Because the next command `vagrant` gives me an error that `Vagrantfile` doesn't exists.

Comment: Well, it's all executed in one shell; I guess you shouldn't pipe (`|`) the output of `cd` to vagrant, but rather use `cd ~/ToMyProject && vagrant ssh ...`?!